# AP scan and OnClickListener

Tags: android, android-wifi

I have written a code which ran :

```
public class WifiActivity extends Activity {

    private ListView listeViewWifi;
    private List<WifiItem> listeWifiItem;
    private WifiAdapter wifiAdapter;
    private WifiManager wifiManager;
    private WifiBroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver;
    private Timer timer;
    private Timer2 timer2;
    private boolean success;
    private boolean broadcastFinish;
    private Button buttonMeasure;
    private Button buttonLocate;
    private EditText coordX;
    private EditText coordY;
    private float[][][] radioMap = new float[100][100][5];




    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_wifi);
       listeViewWifi = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewWifi);
           wifiManager = (WifiManager) this.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

               if(wifiManager != null){
                   wifiManager.startScan();}

                       // On récupère le service WiFi d'Android
                       wifiManager = (WifiManager) this.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

                       // Gestion de la liste des AP WiFi (voir tuto sur les adapters et les
                       // listviews)
                       listeWifiItem = new ArrayList<WifiItem>();
                       wifiAdapter = new WifiAdapter(this, listeWifiItem);
                       listeViewWifi.setAdapter(wifiAdapter);

                       // Création du broadcast Receiver
                       broadcastReceiver = new WifiBroadcastReceiver();

                       // On attache le receiver au scan result
                       registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
                       timer = new Timer(this);
                       timer.applyTimer();

                       [...]


            public void tempsFini(){

                broadcastFinish = WifiBroadcastReceiver.getBroadcastFinish();
                Log.d("info3","broadcastFinish (activity) : " + broadcastFinish);
                 if(broadcastFinish == true){
                     success = false;
                    while(success==false){
                    success=wifiManager.startScan();
                        Log.d("info2","startScan : " + success);
                    }   
                }
            }
```

Then this is the timer method :

```
public class Timer {

    private WifiActivity activity;
    private Handler h = new Handler();
    private Runnable run = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.d("info3","timer");
                activity.tempsFini();   //on met à jour le truc wifi
                h.postDelayed(this, 200); //Donc revient toutes les 200ms
            }
        }
    ;

    public Timer(WifiActivity wifiActivity){
        activity = (WifiActivity) wifiActivity;
    }

    public void applyTimer() {
        h.postDelayed(run, 0); //run est en fait vraiment instancié ici
    }

    public void cancelTimer(){
        h.removeCallbacks(run);
    }
}
```

This program ran. I have made some changes, because I want to make AP scan when I click on a button.

```
buttonMeasure = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonMeasure);

buttonMeasure.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        //Envoyer une moyenne de mesure pour chaque RSSI

       Log.d("info7","onClick");

       coordX = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.coordX);
       coordY = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.coordY);

       String xString = coordX.getText().toString();
       final int xInt = Integer.parseInt(xString);

       String yString = coordY.getText().toString();
       final int yInt = Integer.parseInt(yString);

       timer2 = new Timer2(this); //****

       while(WifiBroadcastReceiver.getMeasureFinished()<=49){
           Log.d("info7","mesure" + WifiBroadcastReceiver.getMeasureFinished());


           timer2.applyTimer(); 
       }

       for(int i=0;i<=4;i++){
           radioMap[xInt][yInt][i]=WifiBroadcastReceiver.getRSSI(i);
       }
    }
});
```

The method timer2 is the same that timer, I have just changed :

```
public Timer2(OnClickListener onClickListener){
    activity = (WifiActivity) onClickListener; //****
}
```

But now the code doesn't work... The Logcat shows errors on the lines where I have commented ****.

Do you know how can I proceed to solve this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OnClickListener cannot be casted to an Activity.
Instead of

```
timer2 = new Timer2(this);
```

use:

```
timer2 = new Timer2(WifiActivity.this);
```

and make your function just like before:

```
public Timer2(WifiActivity wifiActivity){
    activity = (WifiActivity) wifiActivity;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this has solved this problem :) Now my problem is that the while loop is always repeated because timer2.applyTimer() doesn't work, like if this line doesn't exist. However this method worked in the previous code. What could be the problem?